# Connecting to a network folder with username/password in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I often access shared network folders in Powershell to grab files etc. But if the share requires a username/password, Powershell does not prompt me for these, unlike Windows Explorer. If I connect to the folder first in Windows Explorer, Powershell will then allow me to connect.

How can I authenticate myself in Powershell?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

At first glance one really wants to use [`New-PSDrive`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176915.aspx) supplying it credentials.

```
> New-PSDrive -Name P -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\server\share -Credential domain\user
```

#### Fails!

```
New-PSDrive : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Dynamic parameters for NewDrive cannot be retrieved for the 'FileSystem' provider. The provider does not support the use of credentials. Please perform the operation again without specifying credentials.
```

The documentation states that you can provide a `PSCredential` object but if you look closer the cmdlet does not support this yet. Maybe in the next version I guess.

Therefore you can either use `net use` or the `WScript.Network` object, calling the [`MapNetworkDrive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kst88h6(VS.80).aspx) function:

```
$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
$net.MapNetworkDrive("u:", "\\server\share", $false, "domain\user", "password")
```

---

### Edit for [New-PSDrive in PowerShell 3.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849829.aspx)

Apparently with newer versions of PowerShell, the `New-PSDrive` cmdlet works to map network shares with credentials!

```
New-PSDrive -Name P -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\Server01\Public -Credential user\domain -Persist
```

Comment: There's an open bug for this: https://connect.microsoft.com/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=334084&SiteID=99

Comment: Actually, I think the cmdlet supports it just fine - it's the underlying PSDrive provider that isn't doing anything with it. All the *-Item cmdlets have a generic set of behaviors; they just pass them through to the PSDrive provider, though. -filter is another example.

Comment: Note that [as of Powershell 3.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849829.aspx), you can pass credentials when connecting a drive to UNC paths, and if you use the `-Persist` option, the drive will be created as a normal Windows mapped drive.

Comment: @BaconBits. Thank you for letting me know on this! I've updated the question to reflect the 3.0 version of PowerShell.

Comment: In powershell 5.1 (and 6) this still does not appear to work when connecting to a domain computer from a non-domain computer, even when supplying working creds. Like OP, once you open the location in the Root param using windows explorer and supplying creds, you can then New-PSDrive after that.

Comment: All this answer are binding it to an drive. Which is not requested in the question. The net use answer push the use of UNC Path, which should work with PS too

Answer (score 57):

This is not a PowerShell-specific answer, but you could authenticate against the share using "NET USE" first:

```
net use \\server\share /user:<domain\username> <password>
```

And then do whatever you need to do in PowerShell...

Comment: This is one of those "use what works" cases where I agree with Anon.  Normally, I would go out of my way to provide a PowerShell answer but not this time.  :)

Comment: This is good way to access windows share from other languages.

Comment: I still haven't found an other way in powershell to do this:   net use \\server\ipc$ /user:<domain\username> password         ->    cd \\server\share

Comment: You can use this method with conjunction of 
```
$networkCreds = $creds.GetNetworkCredential()
$username = "$($networkCreds.Domain)\$($networkCreds.UserName)"
$password = $networkCreds.Password
```

Answer (score 9):

[PowerShell 3 supports this out of the box](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/improving-the-filesystem-provider-through-community-feedback/) now.

If you're stuck on PowerShell 2, you basically have to use the legacy `net use` command (as suggested earlier).

Comment: Dead link! 1 2 3

Answer (score 3):

You can use the New-SmbMapping CMDlet.

```
New-SmbMapping -RemotePath '\\server\path' -UserName 'server\user' -Password 'passwort'
```

You don't have to use the -LocalPath parameter, so it does not mount it as a drive. It just establishes the connection to the share.