# NET USE only works once in powershell

Tags: powershell

My requirement is to connect to a remote computer, copy files with the extension of `.TRA` to a different remote computer.

Now my difficulty arises in that the source machine aren't on the domain so I need to connect with alternate credentials.

My first sticking point is trying to use `New-PSDrive`. It doesn't appear to allow me to pass stored credentials. I have tried various versions of this:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
New-PSDrive -NAME Z: -PSprovider Filesystem -root \\Computer\Exchange -credentials $cred
```

and I get an error

> The provider does not support the use of credentials. Perform the operation again without specifying credentials.

This appears to be a bug (see halr9000's comment here : [Connecting to a network folder with username/password in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/connecting-to-a-network-folder-with-username-password-in-powershell))

My alternative was to use `NET USE`, which works fine but only once.

In the full script below I map to 8 different machines. The first of these works. After that any attempt to use `NET USE` (or `New-Object WScript.NETWORK`, mentioned as a work around on the Technet article linked above) fails. Or rather it doesn't fail.

Its creates a mapped drive, which I can see if I type `NET USE`, or if I look in explorer (and its browsable). But I cannot connect to that drive in Powershell. Its like it doesn't exist, `Test-Path Z:` returns False. Right up until I run `NET USE Z: /D` which successfully deletes the drive.

Can someone please help me with one or other of my issues please? Don't make me do this in DOS!

Full script :

```
$int = 0
$arrStagePC = "BOX42", "BOX43", "BOX44", "BOX45", "BOX46", "BOX47", "BOX48", "BOX49" 
$arrData = "0848","5144","5292","5383","2158","2646","0061","2331"
Foreach($strComp in $arrStagePC)
    {
    $arr = $arrData[$int]
    $comp = $strComp
    net use z: \\$arr\Exchange /user:admin password
    Copy-Item z:\*$date.tra \\$comp\Export$
    net use z: /d
    $int++
    }
```

**EDIT**
Have a look at @Christians accepted answer below. I didn't actually need to Get-Content that folder, I just needed to copy data from the source so the bit of the script doing the business on there now looks like :

```
Foreach($strComp in $arrStagePC)
        {
        $arr = $arrData[$int]
        $comp = $strComp
        net use z: \\$arr\Exchange /user:admin password
        Copy-Item FILESYSTEM::Z:\*.TRA \\$comp\Export$
        net use z: /d
        $int++
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using NET USE try access in this way:

```
 Set-Location  FILESYSTEM::Z:
```

Comment: Absolutely amazing. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Had same issue. Mended mine by adding 
*New-PSDrive z FileSystem z:*
after the NET USE. Seems like NET USE /DELETE disturbs the PS housekeeping.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, maybe:

```
$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
$net.MapNetworkDrive("Z:", "\\$arr\Exchange", $false, "admin", "password")
```

Comment: Unfortunately that results in exactly the same behaviour as the NET USE command, in that it appears to create the drive (and Z: would be visible in Explorer) but Powershell can't use it.