# How can I use spaces in a fully qualified pathname in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that copies a number of files from different sources to a single directory for backup. The only step of the script the errors out has a space in both the path and file names: `\\server\Network Shares\Transfer\tu3\tu3 Code.mdb`

I get the error `copy-item : Cannot find path '\\server\Network Shares\Transfer\tu3\tu3 Code.mdb' because it does not exist.` and I'm **assuming** it's because of the spaces in either the path or filename. Does PowerShell allow spaces in a fully qualified path? If not, how can I get at the file?

Here's the relevant code (My`$Dest`is defined as a global variable for the script):

```
 $TU3CodeUpdatedPathname = "\\server\Network Shares\Transfer\tu3\"
 $TU3CodeUpdatedFilename = "tu3 Code.mdb"
 $TU3CodeUpdated         = $TU3CodeUpdatedPathname + $TU3CodeUpdatedFilename
 #
 $Source = $TU3CodeUpdated
 $Dest   = $VMShareSpacePathname
 #
 copy-item $Source $Dest
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try being more explicit, and wrap the parameter values in quotes. Adding -Verbose might help with debugging. If it's complaining the file doesn't exist, maybe double check that the file is indeed accessible when your script runs under the account, if it's not the same as your user account.

```
  Copy-Item -Path "$Source" -Destination "$Dest"
```

Comment: I must say that the documentation around quoting arguments is very poor on MSDN. I had a variable  $a= "$env:systemroot\Panther\UnattendGC\setupact.log". Now i had to pass the value of $a to another cmdlet which accepts a -Path argument. I had a tough time getting it to work. After seeing your post, all that i had to do was to enclose the arguments again in double quotes.  Has this been explained anywhere clearly? On the command prompt, its understood that paths with spaces need to be quoted. However, this is not very clear for cmdlets. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Just to ensure, you might have mixed up the variable names TU3/HS3?

```
$TU3CodeUpdatedPathname = "\\server\Network Shares\Transfer\tu3\"
$TU3CodeUpdatedFilename = "tu3 Code.mdb"
$TU3CodeUpdated         = Join-Path -Path $TU3CodeUpdatedPathname -ChildPath $TU3CodeUpdatedFilename
```

Otherwise I can't see anything wrong with your code.
Spaces are just fine within quotes as you did write it.

I would guess the running user from the script does not have access rights to the file/share.
[This post might help in that case.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/connecting-to-a-network-folder-with-username-password-in-powershell)

Comment: Ooops...poor coding on my part. HU3 are global, TU3 are local to the function. In this particular case the value ended up identical, but I did change the code for clarity. Good catch! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me to copy folder with space in its name. I am using powershell 4.0

```
$Source = "D:\test\Test cases"
$Dest = "D:\bck\Test cases"
Copy-Item -Path "$Source" "$Dest" -Recurse
```